# c# SerialPort MultiDrop connection

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have been reading up on the web and cannot find any information on working with a RS485 MultiDrop connection in c#

To give a bit of insight. I have written an application to communicate with a Serial device using the MODBUS RTU protocol. Now the client has informed me there devices may be hooked up using multidrop communications links. Being a novice when it comes to working with serial devices I am a bit lost here.

My question is simply: Where do I start? a Google search has thus far only produced hardware converters and wikipedia entries for different Serial Communication standards.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RS485 is a standard that defines the electrical characteristics of a particular multi-drop networking arrangement.  I once used it as the internal bus for an instrument - the main control board drove various pumps which were arranged on an RS485 network.

You can get half-duplex and full duplex arrangements (half means that one device can talk at a time - full means send and receive can happen at the same time).

Really using it is not a whole lot different from using an RS232 or serial port, and as you've seen you can get serial to RS485 converters.  You can use the serial port drivers in C# to use it.

[SerialPort Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)

Your main problem is that RS485 doesn't really address how it should be used - its a fairly low level electrical spec, it doesn't define how you should use it to make communication happen.

The main issue you need to consider is how you're going to coordinate all this.  With RS232 - there are two things connected, which makes it easy - usually a computer and some device.  With RS485, there are many things connected.  So you need some way of addressing each device.  You don't give any details about the 'device' referred to here - but if they are intended to be connected on RS485 - then there will be a way of addressing them.  There are however several ways this could work - so I can't help you on specifics without more detail.  With the system I developed, all communication was initiated by the 'master' device (i.e. my control board - or your c# application for example) and each message sent had the receiver's address on it - so the right pump knew that the instruction was intended for it.

I hope this is of some help.  Really its not that complicated, but you need to think about what these devices do, how they are addressed, and think about the messages that you need to send back and forth.  You can use the C# SerialPort classes to actually do the work.

The book referred to in the other answer looks great by the way.  I really would consider buying it if this is all new to you.  It covers serial port communications, and has a chapter on RS485.

Comment: I should also point out that USB itself is nothing like Serial Ports.  Yes you can get USB serial port converters, but these are devices that plug into a USB port, but look like a serial port to your application software.

Comment: Thank you that was extremely helpful. My 'device' is a automation control device that my company produces... so not really any specs on it that you would be able to find. I am communicating to it using the MODBUS RTU protocol. I was confused because the terminology i was being given was wrong. They just wanted the ability to select different slave devices from a list of available slaves. my application is the master. your answer is well written and informative. check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with RS485 but [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193144806X)  can be a help in understanding Serial port and USBs.

[here](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-485.html) is another link which discuss specs and [here](http://www.bb-elec.com/tech_articles/rs422_485_app_note/overview.asp) is another. I dont think they will be readily implemented in C# but could be.